# Sigmajs custom forces

Tags: d3.js, sigma.js

Is there a possibility to define custom forces with sigmajs analogue to d3?
And later also manipulate the forces?

I.e in d3 I can define a force:

```
simulation
.force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
    return d.id;
}))
.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

and later I can manipulate for example the force on the link:

```
simulation.force("link").strength(function(link) {

    return (somecondition) ? 0.2 : 1.0;
});
```

Is there some way to do this in sigmajs?